# What is this upside down floating heart symbolizing?

Tags: symbolism, nichijou

In the Nichijou short 8, Yuuko Aioi goes fishing.
After fishing up a boot and kettle, she leaves and this upside down heart shape on a leave floats by.

[image]

Supposedly this is a symbolism of sorts, hence what is this symbolizing?

Comment: Looks like a peach which refers to *Momotaro*, though I don't know the connection with the story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a peach. As Aki Tanaka commented, this is a reference to the story of [Momotaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momotar%C5%8D), in which an old woman finds a peach floating down a river. When she and her husband attempt to eat it, they find a boy inside.